# Jquery Checkbox Validar null?

Tags: jquery, razor

Tengo una checkbox list hecha en MVC Razor:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Categories[i].Value);
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Categories[i].Text);
            <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Categories[i].Selected, new { @class = "CategoriesClass", value = false, id = "Categories" })&nbsp;@Model.Categories[i].Text</label>
            <br />
        }
        <span id="Categories-error" class="field-validation-error">
            <label style="font:weight:bold; color:#a94442;">Seleccione al menos una Categoria.</label>
        </span>
        <br/>
```

Y trato de utilizar el siguiente Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var declarationsError = $('#Categories-error');
$('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(".CategoriesClass:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
        declarationsError.hide();
        return true;
    } else {
        declarationsError.show();
        return false;
    }
});

$('.CategoriesClass').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        declarationsError.hide();
    } 
});

$('.CategoriesClass').click(function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        declarationsError.show();
    }
});
```

La parte del submit funciona, es decir si el usuario presiona el botón Submit y los checkboxes estan en NULL, activa la validación indicando que debe seleccionar al menos una categoría.

A su vez ese mensaje se muestra al comienzo y desaparece cuando el usuario clickea en un checkbox. Al clickear nuevamente, este re-aparece lo cual está bien.

El problema radica cuando se maneja la selección múltiple, es decir si el usuario elije dos opciones y descheckea una, el mensaje se muestra "debe seleccionar al menos una categoría" lo cual es incorrecto porque ya tiene una seleccionada.

¿Hay alguna manera mejor de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví reemplazando las opciones de .change y .click por esto:

```
    var countChecked = function () {
    var n = $(".CategoriesClass:checkbox:checked").length;
    if (n == 0) {

        declarationsError.show();

    } else declarationsError.hide();
};
countChecked();

$('.CategoriesClass').on("click", countChecked);
```

Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Iba a responder algo muy similar pero es bueno que hayas hallado la solución tú mismo, de hecho si agregas un return `true|false` puedes usarlo también para el evento `submit` y ahorrar líneas. Deberías marcarlo como respuesta correcta para futuras referencias.